# How to properly format python code structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I'm still a bit new to python and I am trying to learn how to properly format my code for real world applications and interviews.

The code below takes a number as an input and then returns how many numbers in a list are above and below the given number. I create a class, `solution`, to store the function ,`placeOfNum`, that does all of the processing logic.

If I want to output my answer as I have below is it best practice call the `Solution` class function as I have below, or should I keep everything in the class to help with readability, or should I make another function, `answer` for example, within the class and output the solution within that class?

```
def placeOfNum(self, n, array):
    aboveNum = 0 
    belowNum = 0
    array = sorted(array)

    for x in array: 
        if x < n: 
            belowNum += 1
        if x > n: 
            aboveNum += 1 
     return (above, below)

numList = [1,5,21,2,1,10,232]
num = 21
x = Solution()

answer = x.placeOfNum(num, numList)
print("above:", answer[0], "below:", answer[1])

# returns "above:1, below:5"
```

Comment: You never refer to `self` in the only  method defined for `Solution`. You don't need a class *at all*. (That said, is `findPlace` supposed to be `placeOfNum`?) Python isn't Java; you can define functions outside of a class.

Comment: This code might fit [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) better

Comment: Also, if you are interviewing for a job that requires Python, I would use [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) standard style, so e.g don't use `camelCase`  names, use `snake_case`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def place_of_num(num, array):
    above_num = 0 
    below_num = 0

    for x in array: 
        if x < num: 
            below_num += 1
        if x > num: 
            above_num += 1
    return tuple((above_num, below_num))

num_list = sorted([1,5,21,2,1,10,232])
num = 21

answer = place_of_num(num, num_list)
print(f"above: {answer[0]} and below: {answer[1]}")
```

I would have written it this way. keep the naming consistent like using snake_case for variables, function, and CamelCase for Class names. keep the code simple and readable

Comment: why are you sorting outside the function? That's more than a stylistic change

Comment: I don't find the need to sort the list inside a function. do you think it is bad practice?

Comment: But then it is a different function, not a style change. I agree, it doesn't seem necessary to sort at all.

Comment: ok, please feel free to edit the answer on how exactly it should be done.